# Elastic search isn't giving correct results for 1 field search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

I have 3 record entries with name fields as follows
1) apple-pineapple
2) apple-pine
3) apple

I am making the below query

```
{
 "type": [
   "Forest::Meditaranian::Fruits"
 ],
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [{
       "query_string": {
         "analyze_wildcard": true,
         "default_operator": "and",
         "fields": ["name"],
         "lenient": true,
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "query": "apple-pi*"
       }
     }],
     "must_not": [{
       "query_string": {
         "analyze_wildcard": true,
         "default_operator": "and",
         "fields": ["status"],
         "lenient": true,
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "query": "deactivated"
       }
     }]
   }
 },
 "limit": 50,
 "offset": 0,
 "all_projects": false
}
```

This is giving me zero hits. 
Cases:
1) `"fields": ["name","xyzdummyentryhere"]` -->  2 hits
2) `"fields": ["name"]` --> 0 hits

If i search for name apple-*
3) `"fields": ["name"]` --> 2 hits
If i search for name apple-pi*
0 hits
How should i form the query so that i get 2 hits for apple-pi* ?

Analyser used

'raw_lower': {'type': 'string',
                                      'analyzer': 'keyword_lowercase'}

Comment: What analyzer are you using? during Index time

Comment: 'dynamic': True           'raw_lower': {'type': 'string',
                                      'analyzer': 'keyword_lowercase'}

Comment: I think just for ease update your question and add the mappings etc.